# how to get count and different between records of an action in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to create the aggregation method to get the result of this equation
 `e = ((s1-s)/(t1-t))`

`s1 = s` of current record
`s = s` of prev record
and 
`t1 = t` of current record
`t = t` of prev record

I have this records in MongoDB

Record View

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d9e7b4ad433ce84a235e93"), 
    "s" : NumberInt(100), 
    "t" : NumberInt(10), 
    "z" : NumberInt(1)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d9e7d0ad433ce84a235e95"), 
    "s" : NumberInt(80), 
    "t" : NumberInt(19), 
    "y" : NumberInt(2)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d9e7d2ad433ce84a235e97"), 
    "s" : NumberInt(3), 
    "t" : NumberInt(30), 
    "y" : NumberInt(3)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d9e7d4ad433ce84a235e99"), 
    "s" : NumberInt(4), 
    "t" : NumberInt(42), 
    "y" : NumberInt(3)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d9e7d7ad433ce84a235e9b"), 
    "s" : NumberInt(3), 
    "t" : NumberInt(50), 
    "z" : NumberInt(5)
}
```